# Lamella Face Displacement

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I need a Shader or a Geonode Setup which Displaces the face in like in the pattern of picture 1 but with the cross-section of the geometry in picture 2. So the shadows created by the geometry create the pattern.
I have provided my Setup of shading so far if it helps.
[image: The pattern]
[image: The cross section i want on the surface]
[image: My Setup so far]

Thank you for you'r help

Comment: It could also be done as an array along a curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the mesh I'll use.

[image]

In geonodes, you can create a curve and resample it to give it as many points as you want.

[image]

Then you can *Instance on Points* your original geometry from the *Group Input* node.

[image]

Now, of course, my size position and rotation needed adjustment, but there you go.